# Как сделать swiper-slider так , чтобы слайды выходили за границу контейнера?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать такой слайдер? Если ширина контейнер сайта такая же как и ширина центрального слайда.Я пробовал отменить oveflow: hidden  у слайдера, тогда появляется полоса прокрутки снизу , которая не нужна, и не должна присутствовать.Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о swiperjs, то swiper-wrapper остается 100%
А вот swiper-slide необходимо перебить ширину на свою.
Например я ставил 80% (что бы с правой стороны виднелся следующий слайд.
Вам необходимо только не прижимать его к левой стороне.

[image: пример]